# Speed up Oracle multi-table query with ORDER BY clause

Tags: sql, oracle10g, query-optimization

I have the following three tables (there are actually many more fields, but this should give an idea of what I'm trying to achieve):

```
log (
  eventId INTEGER,
  objectId INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY (eventId)
)

objects (
  objectId INTEGER,
  typeId INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY (objectId, typeId)
)

statusBits (
  typeId INTEGER,
  bitNumber INTEGER,
)
```

The `log` table contains a very large number of records (500,000+), while the other tables are quite small. I can join the tables using the following query:

```
SELECT l.eventId, o.typeId, s.bitNumber
FROM log l, objects o, statusBits s
WHERE (l.objectId = o.objectId) AND (o.typeId = s.typeId)
```

This query runs nice and fast. It also runs fast when I add an `ORDER BY eventId` clause at the end. However, when I add `ORDER BY eventId, bitNumber` (thus sorting by two fields rather than one) it becomes painfully slow.

How can I optimise my query to that it runs faster? I am running Oracle 10g XE if that makes any difference.

**UPDATE:**
I've already tried `CREATE INDEX ON statusBits(bitNumber)` but it doesn't seem to have a great effect.

Comment: Can you add the explain plan for both queries?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i'll refactor your query as follow:

```
SELECT L.eventId
    ,O.typeId
    ,S.bitNumber
FROM log L
INNER JOIN objects O ON O.objectId = L.objectId
INNER JOIN statusBits S ON S.typeId = O.typeId
```

It may probably not help for your execution time but the query is much more readable and the use of `INNER JOIN` is a best practice.

Then in order to optimise your execution time, the first solution that comes in mind is to create an index but you've already tested that. It may help to try a concatenated index instead of a simple index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON statusBits (typeId, bitNumber);
```

Hope this will help.